# How do I bind the foreground of a textblock to a color/brush object?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, colors, textblock

I want to bind a textblock foreground property to a color object (or a brush object, I don't know which is the right one).
My colours and brushes are stored in a class called Colours (Colours.MyColour for example) so I set the DataContext like so:

```
DataContext="{Binding} Colours"
```

And bound the foreground property like so:

```
<TextBlock Text="Text" Foreground="{Binding MyColour}"/>
```

It doesn't work so I'm clearly doing it wrong. Could someone let me know?

Comment: It is not working because your datacontext is a string itself containing a simple text... You should try to set the datacontext to a **instance** of the class that you said is holding the colors property.... Also the type of that property should also be the same as the Foreground property. And, don't forget to use the INotifyPropertyChange to notify you view when something change in the model.... I guess it is enough to start... take care of your pets.

Comment: Why do you set the DataContext? Secondly how do you declare instance of the Colours class and +1 for spelling colour correctly.

Comment: It's actually a static class. Does the foreground need a Color or a Brush?

Comment: And how do you reference that static class in your xaml? And here is [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock.foreground?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Controls_TextBlock_Foreground) link for TextBlocks Foreground property.

Comment: Foreground is a brush, as are fill, stroke and background. Maybe you should be using resources rather than a class. Put your standard colours and brushes in a resourcedictionary merged into application.current.resources in app.xaml. you can then use tyese as staticresource - or dynamicresource if you intend them to change.

Answer (score 0):

The [`TextBlock.Foreground`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock.foreground) property is a `Brush`, so the members of `Colours` should also be of type `Brush`.

Your comments say that `Colours` is a `static` class. If that's the case, you should be able to reference it using [`x:Static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/xaml-services/xstatic-markup-extension) like so:

```
<TextBlock Text="Text" Foreground="{x:Static local:Colours.MyColour}"/>
```

Note that you need to specify the namespace where `Colours` is defined. Additional namespaces are referenced in your XAML file at the top using [`xmlns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml). By default, the namespace of the current project is added as "local", hence the `local:` in `local:Colours.MyColour`.